# I can refresh keycloak token in Postman, but I can't it in browser

Tags: frontend, keycloak, refresh-token

When I refresh token in Postman everything is ok
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9nhg.png)
But when I do it in browser I have a error like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E72H5.png)
My Payload[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29Vzh.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your UI has some issues with using the refresh-token. Pease try the folowing: copy the token to https://jwt.io/ and see if a "refresh_token" is available in the decrypted object. If not you have the root cause.